# What is the simplest way to adjust the input voltage for a linear regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

I have a garage door opener for which I need to replace the radio receiver. The opener outputs a DC supply voltage for a receiver at 34 VDC. The receiver has an input range specification of 12-24 V AC/DC.

I'm attaching a photo of the receiver's input stage below. It consists of an MB6S bridge rectifier and a 78L05 (SOT-98) linear regulator with 5 V output.

According to the datasheets I could find for the 78L05 it has an input-voltage range of 7-20 V with 30 V absolute maximum. It has 220 uF/50 V input and output filter caps and apparently a 51 R series input resistor. The receiver has a specified input current of < 10 mA.

What would be the simplest modification or addition to the receiver's input that would make it compatible with the 34 V supply voltage?

[image: receiver input stage]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would cut the trace after the MB6S's positive terminal and replace it with a 15V zener, like this:

[image]

This way, the input cap will 'see' around 19V, which would be in spec.

Comment: Be aware that that zener's gonna be dissipating a lot of power, dependent on current draw; get a big one. Do the math and see if you need a 5 W zener or if a 3 W one will do.

Comment: OP said it's consuming < 10mA, so even a small DO-35 500mW zener diode will work.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution indeed. However, I'll measure the input current with a 12 V input before I try this. I've grown suspicious of the 10 mA specification in the receiver's data sheet, as the relay coils alone each seem to have a power consumption of 450 mW.

Comment: @tg85, checking it is definitely a good idea. But it seems, if the 78L05 supplied the coil current, it would have been fried at 24V input, as the SOT-89 would have had to dissipate more than 1.7 watts